# Create multiple item versions based on mobile platform - Web API

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using sitecore 8.1 and I've used multiple languages for items, so I can get item by a specific language which is fully supported by Sitecore, now I need to do the same but I need Item content to be vary by another aspect which is **Mobile Platform**, this means that I need **the same item** to have contents of some fields for Android platform, and different content for IOS platform **without creating new item for each platform and with keeping some item fields shared between all platforms** ..

At the beginning I thought that I can achieve that by using **Item Versions** which is supported by Sitecore as well .. but then I read that only latest version of item will be available after publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for the presentation by using devices, but for actual data (fields) it is not possible out of the box. You could create different fields (maybe even in separate sections) to achieve this, but it will be your own code that is somehow responsible for getting the right content out.

A first though could be to create a generic function to fetch the necessary data, in which you cast the items to objects (maybe use Glass?). By using generics you could create classes based on the platforms and use those to only expose the corresponding fields. This would make it quite flexible if you ever need to add platforms.

Comment: Thanks .. As you've suggested at the beginning .. , I've created new sections with duplicating fields' names (which supposed to vary by platform), then created 'SectionFilter' in my API Controller have solved this issue